# draw table 10x10 and display prime number in tables

Tags: java, jsp

need to display like that:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

but i'm getting

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table of prime numbers</title>

    <style>
            .chess-board {border-collapse: collapse; position:absolute; left: 640px; top: 240px;}
            .chess-board td { border: 1px solid; width: 2em; height: 2em; }
            .chess-board .light { background: #eee; }

        </style>

</head>
<body>

<table class="chess-board">
    <tbody>
    <%
        int i,count;
        for(int j=2;j<=541;j++)
            {
            count=0;
            for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
            {
               if(j%i==0)
               {
                    count++;
               }
            }

            if(count==2)

             %>
              <tr></tr>
              <td class="light"><%out.print(j);%></td>
            <%
            }
            %>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to display prime numbers in 10x10 table

but in result i'm getting this, everything in one line
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toZiX.png)

Comment: Hi , prime number starting from 1 to ?

Comment: hi prime number starting from 2 to 541

Comment: There will be 100 tds in 10 * 10 all numbers will not come .

Answer (score 0):

The resulting html will look like that:

```
...
<tbody>
    ...
    <tr></tr>
    <td class="light">2</td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td class="light">3</td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td class="light">4</td>
    ...
</tbody>
...
```

This is not valid html code. You can use "view source" or "inspect" in your browser to see the result as html. It should be like that:

```
...
<tbody>
    ...
    <tr>
      <td class="light">2</td>
      <td class="light">3</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="light">12</td>
      <td class="light">13</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

Try to modify your code so that it produces that kind of html.
...